# How to svn up each ancestor directory given a path string?

Tags: bash, shell, svn, csh

I want to svn up a file inside a deep path. `a/b/c/d.py`, is it possible to make a one liner csh or bash script to do the following? If one liner is not possible, how do I do it in a script?

```
# a b c directories do not exist in local working copy at the
# beginning, and they contain other files and directories
svn up a --depth empty
svn up a/b --depth empty
svn up a/b/c --depth empty
svn up a/b/c/d.py --depth empty
```

imagined usage

```
someAliasOrScript a/b/c/d.py
```

edit: I am using an svn 1.7.1, and I can not update to latest 1.9.5

> svn up a/b/c/d.py                                                                                                                                               Skipped 'a/b/c/d.py'
>   Summary of conflicts:
>     Skipped paths: 1

I am inside a newly checked out working copy root dir

```
> svn info
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: xxx
URL: xxx
Repository Root: xxx
Repository UUID: xxx
Revision: xxx
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Depth: empty
Last Changed Author: xxx
Last Changed Rev: xxx
Last Changed Date: xxx
```

Then I tried svn 1.9.5 as well, the error is

```
Skipped 'a/b/c/d.py'
svn: E155007: None of the targets are working copies
```

Comment: Have you tried to run `svn update PATH-TO-FILe`? It should work without any special scripts. I don't understand why you ask this question.

Comment: It did not work so I asked the question, yes I have tried that, see updated info.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly update your file using the last command:

```
svn up a/b/c/d.py
```

This will only update d.py file.

EDIT: That only works as an updating tool. As far as I understood, you are talking about doing the first checkout. Therefore you do need to do:

```
 svn co a --depth empty
 svn up a/b --depth empty
 svn up a/b/c --depth empty
 svn up a/b/c/d.py --depth empty
```

This works for me in svn 1.9.7. Maybe try doing `svn up a/b/c/d.py` instead of `svn up a/b/c/d.py --depth empty` as you are updating a file.

Also, this seems a case where you'd want to only check out folder c (why having multiple layers?)

Comment: It does not work for me for some reason. Check my updated error info

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: This did not answer my question, I want to complete these commands in one line, because I don't want to svn up them one by one. And in order to simplify the question, I have said in original question that, I have checked out the top local working directory, meaning there is another `root` dir above `a`, and I have run `svn co root --depth empty`